# Deploying G Suite Marketplace app using a manifest. (G Drive UI Integration)

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-apps-marketplace, google-drive-shared-drive

Right now G Suite Marketplace can be deployed via creating and configuring a project in http://console.developers.google.com, but suppose I want to deploy an application for a domain only, but for different different admins.

Creating project and doing manual configuration for each domain admin is cumbersome and updating and publishing new one will be difficult. Is there a way to deploy and publish G Suite Marketplace app via Manifest. (Similar to chrome web store).

Comment: Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-cws#publish_your_app), there's no way to deploy and publish G Suite Marketplace app via Manifest.

Comment: But Google Cloud console have different Rest APIs available, is it possible via them? Anyone tried it before?

Comment: Not at the moment. An API to publish G Suite extension is in our roadmap, but we don't have concrete plans yet.

Comment: @AlejandroTamalet, so as of now only way to publish G Suite extensions are using developer console. 
Or some other automation for this task is possible?

Comment: Right, as of now the only way to publish a G Suite extension is using the developer console.